# Retrieve interaction with an issue from your GitHub profile

Tags: github

On Stackoverflow, you can keep track of the questions and answers you interact with by going to your profile and clicking on votes or favourites:
[image: votes and favourites]

If you click the face in a GitHub issue you can add one of six emoticons:

[image: GitHub issue emoticons]

I have never been able to see if this goes anywhere in your profile where you can use it as a bookmark. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible since it is not even possible to get a [list of issues your are following.](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/283)

As far as I know, the only way to "bookmark" an issue in GitHub apart from using your browsers function is commenting and searching for `involves:user`. (Replace user with your actual username. `commenter:user` might be a bit more specific but e.g. misses issues you created yourself.)

I would recommend sending an email to GitHub support so (1) you are absolutely sure and don't have to rely on my assumptions and (2) they might consider adding this as a feature.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know those two search functions you listed were possible, I was able to find every issue I ever posted in without being logged in. Ok, you can retrieve an issue where you posted but not just where you added an emoticon. Am not going to go posting meaningless stuff in issues just to create a bookmark. Might email them, or for now keep track of these things with the browser bookmarks or pasting links in my code.